# GSAP: Pin progress bar when it hits element + progress bar not accrate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gsap, scrolltrigger

I'm trying to create a progress bar that shows how much of a certain element the user still has left to view. Here are some details:

- `.postProgressBar` appears by default under `.postHeroImage`
- When the user scrolls, I want the `.postProgressBar` to slowly fill up based on how much of the `.spacer` element there is left to scroll to.
- When the `.postProgressBar` hits the bottom of my `header`, I want it to become `fixed` to the bottom of the `header` (and to unfix when `.postHeroImage` is in view again).

See my current approach:

```js
$(function() {

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 1) {
      $(".header").addClass("fixed");
    } else {
      $(".header").removeClass("fixed");
    }
  });
  
    var action = gsap.set('.postProgressBar', { position:'fixed', paused:true});

  gsap.to('progress', {
    value: 100,
    ease: 'none',
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: "#startProgressBar",
      scrub: 0.3,
      markers:true,
      onEnter: () => action.play(),
      onLeave: () => action.reverse(),
      onLeaveBack: () => action.reverse(),
      onEnterBack: () => action.reverse(),
    }
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
  --white: #FFFFFF;
  --grey: #002A54;
  --purple: #5D209F;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: var(--white);
}
.header.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: var(--white);
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--grey);
}

.postHeroImage {
  padding: 134px 0 0 0;
  margin-bottom: 105px;
  position: relative;
}
.postHeroImage__bg {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
}

progress {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 9999;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: transparent;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: var(--purple);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: var(--purple);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.spacer {
  height: 1000vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.0/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<body>

  <header class="header">Header</header>

  <section class="postHeroImage" id="startProgressBar">

    <progress class="postProgressBar" max="100" value="0"></progress>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="postHeroImage__bg" style="background-image: url( 'https://picsum.photos/200/300' );" loading="lazy"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <div class="spacer">lorum ipsum</div>

</body>
```

Current issues:

1. The `.postProgressBar` doesn't become `fixed` (can't see `fixed` inline style in inspect mode)
2. The `.postProgressBar` is showing progress that isn't accurate based on the amount of `.spacer` there is left to scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Position [sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) is very useful here. You can use it for header as well as for the progress bar. With no effort it'll keep the elements fixed to top.
2. For accurate position you need to use `start` and `end` properties of the `scrollTrigger`. This will tell the gsap when to start animating and when to end. For end we need to add 64px, the height of the header, to the scrolling cos our container is 64px below from top of the viewport.

   Demo:

```js
$(function() {
  //read the css variable
  let bodyStyles = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
  let headerHeight = bodyStyles.getPropertyValue('--header-height'); 

  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
  gsap.to('progress', {
    value: 100,
    ease: 'none',
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: "#startProgressBar",
      scrub: 0.3,
      start: 'start 0px',
      end: 'bottom' + headerHeight,
      markers: true,
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
  --white: wheat;
  --grey: #002A54;
  --purple: #5D209F;
  /* 40px padding top and bottom + 24px line height*/
  --header-height: 64px;
}

.header {
  /* position: absolute;*/
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: var(--white);
}

.postHeroImage {
  padding: 134px 0 0 0;
  margin-bottom: 105px;
  position: relative;
}

.postHeroImage__bg {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
}

progress {
  position: sticky;
  top: var(--header-height);
  left: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  /*z-index: 9999;*/
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: transparent;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: var(--purple);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: var(--purple);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.spacer {
  height: 1000vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.0/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<header class="header">Header</header>
<section class="postHeroImage" id="startProgressBar">
  <progress class="postProgressBar" max="100" value="0"></progress>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="postHeroImage__bg" style="background-image: url( 'https://picsum.photos/id/705/300/200' );" loading="lazy"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<div class="spacer">lorum ipsum</div>
```

You can play with start and end properties. If you want to track progress on the content only then change `trigger` to `'.container'` .

---

**Solution without sticky**
Here I've used position fixed:

```js
$(function() {
  //read the css variable
  let bodyStyles = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
  let headerHeight = bodyStyles.getPropertyValue('--header-height');

  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

  var action = gsap.set('.postProgressBar', {
    position: 'fixed',
    paused: true
  });

  ScrollTrigger.create({
    trigger: '.postProgressBar',
    start: 'top 64px',
    onEnter: () => action.play(),
    onLeaveBack: () => action.reverse(),
  });

  gsap.to('progress', {
    value: 100,
    ease: 'none',
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: "#mainContent",
      scrub: 0.3,
      end: 'bottom 110%',
      markers: false,
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: lightblue;
  --white: wheat;
  --grey: #002A54;
  --purple: #5D209F;
  /* 40px padding top and bottom + 24px line height*/
  --header-height: 64px;
  position: relative;
  height:100%
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: var(--white);
}

.postHeroImage {
  padding: 134px 0 0 0;
  margin-bottom: 105px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: var(--header-height);
}

.postHeroImage__bg {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
}

progress {
  position: static;
  top: var(--header-height);
  left: 0px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  /*z-index: 9999;*/
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: transparent;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: var(--purple);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: var(--purple);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.spacer {
  height: 1000vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.0/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<header class="header">Header</header>
<section class="postHeroImage" id="startProgressBar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="postHeroImage__bg" style="background-image: url( 'https://picsum.photos/id/705/300/200' );" loading="lazy"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <progress class="postProgressBar" max="100" value="0"></progress>
</section>

<div id="mainContent" class="spacer">lorum ipsum</div>
```

Comment: Hi, is there a way to achieve this without `sticky`? I say this because `sticky` does not work if any parent containers have `overflow: hidden`, which is the case in my build. Additionally, I need the progress bar to show below the image by default and then, when it hits the bottom of the `header`, then I want it to be fixed below the `header`

Comment: I've added solution without sticky. Using original position fixed action.

Comment: Hi again, I'm trying to get the progress bar to indicate how much of the page is left to scroll. For example, in your demo, the the scroll bar is already complete by the time the `.spacer` div is hit. There's still a lot more of the page to scroll, which the bar should indicate. Also, the progress bar is hidden for a bit then gets fixed. Is it possible to have it fix as it's scrolling (smoothly)? See this website for a demo: https://www.magneticcreative.com/journal/hubl-templating-hubspot-cms/

Comment: I thought progress is for the image. I've updated the second snippet in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the library that you use, you could simply use the HTML tag `<progress>` (your library is using the same).

Here is a simple way of how you can do it:

```js
const scrollHeight = Math.max(
  document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
  document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
  document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight
);

window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => document.querySelector('progress').value = window.pageYOffset / (scrollHeight - window.innerHeight) * 100)
```

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 2500px;
}

progress {
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 22px;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: #5D209F;
}
```

```html
<progress value="0" max="100"></progress>
```

Every time the user scrolls the page, the progress gets a value, which is *current height position* / (*document's height* - *active screen height*) * 100.